# Combining \bar with superscripts

Tags: positioning, superscripts

Easy question here but haven't been able to find the answer online. I am trying to create the following symbol in math mode: an `i`, with a bar over it, and then an asterisk as a superscript to the *entire* object.

My initial attempt was the simple `$\bar{i}^*$`, however, the asterisk seems to fall *under* the bar. I need the asterisk to look as if it's the superscripts for *all* of `\bar{i}`. My other (unsuccessful) attempts have included using the empty group `{}` to create a gap between the `\bar{i}` and the superscript, using `\mbox{}` to delimit the `\bar{i}` as admitting a superscript, and simply playing around with placement. In all these cases, however, I still end up with an asterisk that looks to be below or at the same height as the bar, not above. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what your doubt is; if you compare `$A^*$` and `$\bar{i}^*$`, you'll see that the asterisks are at the same height (which is the right one, by the way). If it was the whole “starred i” to have a bar, it would be `$\overline{i^*}$`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, what is being asked here is just a way to circumvent the rule, stated in *The TeXbook*, p. 291, l. 16–17, that prevents `${\bar{i}}^{*}$` from having the desired effect; for this, it suffices to say, *e.g.*, `${\bar{i}{}}^{*}$`, whereby no extra height is introduced.

Here is a complete, compilable source code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % comment or uncomment as preferred

\begin{document}
Compare: $\bar{i}^{*}$, ${\bar{i}}^{*}$, ${\bar{i}{}}^{*}$, $\bar{i}\strut^{*}$.
\end{document}
```

And here is the output it produces:

[image: Output of the above code]

Note that, in the fourth case, the asterisk is rised slightly more than in the third one.

Answer (score 2):

This works.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}



\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
     \bar i^* \quad {\bar i}^* \quad {\bar i\vphantom{\Big|}}^* \quad 
     {\bar i {\Large\mathstrut}}^*
        \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

it's traditional in math publishing to use an undotted i if a diacritic is to be
placed over it. `\imath` is the command for this letter.
(there's a matching `\jmath`.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

$ \bar{\imath}^* \quad \bar{\imath}\strut^* $

$ \bar{\jmath}^* \quad \bar{\jmath}\strut^* $

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

if you feel the asterisk is too low (although it is at the proper place; compare it with `$T^*$` for example), you can insert something taller to raise it.  a `\strut` is used here; the `\mathstrut` doesn't change the position.

Answer (score 0):

You need a larger object to superscript. As an example use `\strut`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$\bar{i}^*\ \bar{i}\strut^*$

\end{document}
```